# Silex Custom Auth with Guard

Tags: php, security, token, silex, symfony-guard

I try to follow the tutorial on the [Silex official website](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/cookbook/guard_authentication.html) but I have an error when the Authenticator is registered as a service.

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to App\Security\TokenAuthenticator::__construct() must be an instance of App\Security\EncoderFactoryInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory given, called in C:\wamp\www\api\src\app.php on line 41 and defined in C:\wamp\www\api\src\App\Security\TokenAuthenticator.php on line 17`

Here is my app.php

```
$app = new Silex\Application(['debug' => true]);

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'main' => array(
        'guard' => array(
            'authenticators' => array(
                'app.token_authenticator'
            ),

            // Using more than 1 authenticator, you must specify
            // which one is used as entry point.
            // 'entry_point' => 'app.token_authenticator',
        ),
        // configure where your users come from. Hardcode them, or load them from somewhere
        // http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider
        'users' => array(
        //raw password = foo
            'test' => array('ROLE_USER', '$2y$10$3i9/lVd8UOFIJ6PAMFt8gu3/r5g0qeCJvoSlLCsvMTythye19F77a'),
        ),
        // 'anonymous' => true
    ),
);

$app['app.token_authenticator'] = function ($app) {
    return new App\Security\TokenAuthenticator($app['security.encoder_factory']);
};

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());

return $app;
```

The `TokenAuthenticator` is the same as the example. How can i configure this service with an argument that implements `App\Security\EncoderFactoryInterface` ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: Just a quick shot, can you try to add a ```use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface``` at the beginning of your TokenAuthenticator.php file? It seems that the namespace for this interfaces is missing

Answer (score 0):

use statement is missing :

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
```